# How does one add shell parameters while executing commands with su?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, su

The situation.
I am debugging the environment of a restricted user who is relagated to a special shell.  In order to do this, I need to run a command as that user in their full context using su like as follows:

```
su - $user -c "echo hello world" --shell /bin/custom_shell
```

I can obviously change the command and the parameters of the command that /bin/custom_shell will execute, but how do I add a parameter that the custom_shell will execute with?
Example equivalent of adding a "--debug" parameter:

```
root->su - $user
$user->/bin/custom_shell --debug --command "echo hello world"
```

Note: sudo will not work for this as there are many profile variables and working directory changes that take place while logging in. Hence the reason that I am using su.
Also, this is a strange intermittent issue that I need to be able to script and run otherwise, su - $user and running the command by hand might work.. However, I don't have that luxury.

Comment: But aren't all those custom profile variables loaded _by_ the user's shell? Does it really matter whether it is invoked by su's --shell and not in another way?

Comment: Yes.. It matters.  sudo -u $user echo 1 is very different from a security and working directory context than su - $user --command "echo 1".

Comment: I think that's mostly because you're passing the `-l` / `--login` option to su, but not to sudo. (And what does --login do, anyway? It runs the shell itself with the -l option. Not much else.)